# SQL filter rows without join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm always "irk" by unnecessary join. But in this case, I wonder if it's possible to not use join.

This is an example of the table I have:

```
id | team | score
 1 |   1  |  300
 2 |   1  |  257
 3 |   2  |  127
 4 |   2  |  533
 5 |   3  |  459
```

This is what I want:

```
team | score | id
  1  |  300  |  1
  2  |  533  |  4
  3  |  459  |  5
```

Doing a query looking like this:
(basically: who's the best player of each team)

```
SELECT team, MAX(score) AS score, id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY team
```

But I get something like that:

```
team | score | id
  1  |  300  |  1
  2  |  533  |  3
  3  |  459  |  5
```

But it's not the third player that got 533 points, so the result have no consistency.

Is it possible to get truthworthy results without joining the table with itself? How to achieve that?

Comment: Please do add [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) or add table structure

Comment: Add an sql fiddle,  you should be able to use ranking to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without joins by using subquery like this:

```
SELECT id, team, score
FROM table1 a
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM table1 b WHERE a.team = b.team);
```

However in big tables this can be very slow as you have to run the whole subquery for every row in your table.

However there's nothing wrong with using join to filter results like this:

```
SELECT id, team, score FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(score) score, team
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY team
    ) b ON a.score = b.score AND a.team = b.team
```

Although joining itself is quite expensive, this way you only have to run two actual queries regardless how many rows are in your tables. So in big tables this method can still be hundreds, if not thousands of times faster than the first method with subquery.

Comment: I was wondering if a one-query way of doing it existed :) As soon as we do sub-queries, there is no point at avoiding `INNER JOIN` ^_^ That's what I did in the end. Even if creative solutions were suggested, they're too complicated for a professionnal use (understandability is a requirement). Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Doesn't this give a Runtime error of "Column 'team' in field list is ambiguous" and "Column 'score' in field list is ambiguous"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT id, team, score
FROM (
  SELECT id, team, score,
         @seq := IF(@t = team, @seq, 
                   IF(@t := team, @seq + 1, @seq + 1)) AS seq,
         @grp := IF(@t2 = team, @grp + 1, 
                   IF(@t2 := team, 1, 1)) AS grp                 
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @t := 0, @grp := 0, @t2 := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY score DESC) AS t
WHERE seq <= 3 AND grp = 1
```

Variable `@seq` is incremented each time a new team is met as the records are being processed in descending `score` order. Variable `@grp` is used to enumerate records within each `team` partition. Records with `@grp = 1` are the ones having the greatest `score` value within the `team` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4d8d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortantly , MySQL doesn't support window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` which could have solved this easily.

There are several ways on doing that:

`NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.team = s.team AND s.score > t.score)
```

`NOT IN()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE (t.team,t.score) IN(SELECT s.team,MAX(s.score)
                          FROM YourTable s
                          GROUP BY s.team)
```

A correlated query:

```
SELECT distinct t.id,t.team,
       (SELECT s.score FROM YourTable s
        WHERE s.team = t.team
        ORDER BY s.score DESC
        LIMIT 1)
FROM YourTable t
```

Or a join which I understand you already have.

**EDIT** : I take my words back, you can do it with a variable like @GiorgosBetsos solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT team, score, id
FROM (SELECT *
             ,RANK() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY score DESC) AS Rank
      FROM my_table) ranked_result
WHERE Rank = 1;
```

Some info on Rank functionality: [Clicketyclickclick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176102.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, did not notice this being MySQL. The above only runs in MSSQL.